# Do certain player skins have tactical advantages in Smite?

Tags: xbox-one, smite

I bought the G.E.B. 1 skin for Geb (the Transformer looking skin), and noticed it changes his X skill, the boulder morph, into a spaceship morph.

The spaceship version of it is definitely wider visually; but, it also seems to have a wider hit box, allowing you to hit more minions in a swath, or have a slightly tighter turning radius when chasing someone.

Are there any other player skins that modify skills to have a slightly different effect? Or do all of the premium (gem only) skins provide a benefit like this? I've  only bought one so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may appear that way, but skins don't affect the god's hitboxes in any way. skins that change the appearance of things, like GEB 1, is purely cosmetic.

You can test this out in jungle practice mode and see for yourself, although... I'm unsure if the XB1 version has jungle practice... if not it's still testable, just would take a bit more effort.

Comment: Xbox One has *Jungle Practice*.